# Failed to parse number '3134-13' in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

i am trying to parse to int but there is an error

> OperationFailure: Failed to parse number '3134-13' in $convert with no onError value: Did not consume whole string.

is there a way to solve this

```
 addFields1 = {
   '$addFields': {
      'convertedend': { '$toInt':"$end"},
      'convertedstart': { '$toInt': "$start" }
   }}

    match1={
    "$match":{"end": { '$not': { '$regex': "/-/" } } 
}
} 

    match2={
    "$match":{"start":{ '$not': { '$regex': "/-/" } } 
}}
 group={
    "$group":{'_id': '$_id', 'convertedend':'$convertedend','convertedstart':'$convertedend'}
}

books.aggregate([match1,match2,addFields1,group])
```

i tried many things but i cant solve it

please help

Comment: if you can give a sample json document, and the expected output, because now we cant see how your data are

Comment: With `$regex`, you don't need the `/`, just use `"-"`

Comment: @joe I tried this too but it does not work

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: where is your data ? u have data like '3134-13' and it couldn't parse to int !